# Framed float with figures

Tags: floats

I'm new in latex,I'm tryin to create a framed float with subfigures and a long text caption that is in line with the text ( does not slide out of the margins)

I've followed so far the following refereces, but so far my attempts were abortive.

The added figure is a scheme of what I'm trying to create.

please keep it simple........

here is what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage[heightadjust=all,valign=c]{floatrow}
\usepackage{fr-subfig}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

%\title{Facing and obstacle}
%\maketitle

\thisfloatsetup{subfloatrowsep=qquad,style=BOXED}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\captionsetup{justification=centering,textfont=small}
\ffigbox{%
\begin{subfloatrow}[3]%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{sub figure a}\label{fig:a}}{%
\includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{sub figure b}\label{fig:b}}{%
\includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\begin{subfloatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{sub figure c}\label{fig:c}}{%
\includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{sub figure d}\label{fig:d}}{%
\includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-a}}
\end{subfloatrow}%
\begin{subfloatrow}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{%
\caption[Long caption figure]{very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font  \label{fig:x}}%
    }
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a minial working example. Show, that you have tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger, added

Comment: First, your figure is too wide for the page.  Second, floatrow is redefining \caption to \smash the contents somehow.  If you measure the total height of the caption it will be reported as 7.73pt.  You can do all this without floatrow, fr-subfig or subfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image only showed the one frame.  Additional frames can be created using `\fbox` and `minipage` in exactly the same way as the first one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}% bundled with caption

\begin{document}

%\title{Facing and obstacle}
%\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\captionsetup{textfont=small}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{sub figure a}\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{sub figure b}\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}\par
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{sub figure c}\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{sub figure d}\label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}\par
\caption[Long caption figure]{very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font very long text with small font  \label{fig:x}}%
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: very good solution, neat and simple, I would remove the justification=centering though.

Comment: I agree.  (Three more words.)